# Teamviewer doesn't show my game screen

Tags: c#, directx

I've been building a 3D engine from scratch using C# and I've tried to show the result to a friend of mine using Teamviewer. When my demo game starts he doesn't see it.
He can only see the last active program on my screen (for example visual studio from which I started the game)

The game engine launches a windows form at start, then directx binds to this form.
It's a fullscreen application with no windows forms borders etc.

Why doesn't teamviewer pick this up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the same reason you can't use the Print key to capture the screen while running a fullscreen game: It's in exclusive mode, other programs can't access it (and will only grab the standard desktop you can't see while in the game).

Probably the easiest solution for this would be not using fullscreen mode. If you don't want window borders, remove those and essentially render in a borderless window filling the desktop. Just keep in mind that you won't be able to control refresh rate while being in this mode (and VSync might be dictated/forced by the window manager).

Comment: Hmm I will give it a try, I don't mind loosing some performance etc since it is only for temporary demo purposes. I hope to get a releaseable version soon with support for all kinds of hardware.